# Charge vs subscription with Stripe

Tags: api, stripe-payments

I'm reading the document from Stripe and I have one point that is fuzzy on my side.

My customer are create in Stripe and automatically a subscription is attached to them. So in my case, each month they will be charge according to their subscription.

Now I read the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges) about the `charge` component and the documentation says:
`To charge a credit or a debit card, you create a charge object.`.

---

Here my questions:

- Do the subscription charges a customer too but each month ?
- Who I can change the currency of a subscription to bill the customer in their currency ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a subscription allows you to attach a plan to a customer so that they are billed automatically on each billing cycle (daily, monthly, etc.). On each new billing cycle an invoice is created that is then paid automatically which leads to a Charge. You can read more about this on Stripe's extensive documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart

As for the currency, you do not set it on the Customer itself. Instead the currency is associated to a Plan. You, as the developer, decide which Plan(s) to attach to a given subscription. You'd ask your customer which currency they want to pay in client-side for example.

Comment: Hello, for currency, if I will like to accept 5 currencies by plan, I will need to create 5 times the plans? One by currency?

Comment: is there any advantages in using Stripe subscription compared to managing yourself with Stripe charges. We are migrating from another processor, I wonder if we can just stick to Charges

Comment: Yes there's the ability to do smart retries for example https://stripe.com/docs/billing/lifecycle#settings